# HTML form post or Ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a form which has many inputs and will need to be broken up and sent to different databases. What would be the more efficient way to do this, with a regular HTML post to a PHP function or posting to an AJAX(or JQUERY?) function. I don't know much of all the options available for posting and processing data, but if clarification is needed please ask.(If it matters, my project is written in PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a big comprehensive form the better way is divide it on small parts and code step-by-step form submission. In this case you can store data with simple PHP request but validate form fields input with AJAX verification.

Comment: The form isn't large per-say, it has 4 fields that go to one table, and a variable amount of fields go to another table(which is linked to the first table)

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML contains inputs such that the values are independent to each other then sending a separate request is good else AJAX is good option.